# Why didn't they try Jarin's suggestion of leaving very slowly?

Tags: plot-explanation, old

At one point in *Old*, Jarin suggests they try to leave the beach very slowly, in order to gradually adapt to the changes in their aging process that were causing them to lose consciousness. At first this idea is dismissed because it could cost them up to 20 years of their lives.

However, as things were becoming more desperate, this idea began to look more like a good plan. (At one point Jarin even tries swimming for help, which was already indicated to be highly difficult/dangerous and might end up taking nearly as long, and later, Trent and Maddox do nothing from night until morning costing the same amount of time). One could also imagine, with a bit of experimentation, they might not even take as long as Jarin expects, or that the aging slows down as they get further from the beach or something, but the whole idea seems to be forgotten, and towards the end they were verging on accepting their fate.

What is the reason they didn't try this?